# WebRTC Solution for Video and Text chat for Android / IOS

Tags: webrtc

Can anyone share a free/open source `WebRTC` sample Solution for Video and Text chat for `Android/IOS` which can be integrated into my `Android/IOS` app?

Answer (score 2):

Try https://connectycube.com/

They use WebRTC for video calls and provide Android and iOS SDKs.

- iOS WebRTC SDK https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/videocalling
- Android WebRTC SDK https://developers.connectycube.com/android/videocalling

You will need to register account, but they offer FREE version as well. I use ConnectyCube Swift SDK for iOS and Kotlin for Android, but they have Objective-C and Java. When I upgraded from free account to dedicated server they migrated my data.

Answer (score 0):

latest samples for WebRTC [iOS](https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios) [Android](https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo)

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this](https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo) will be helpful for Webrtc audio/video calling in android